# Pi stuck on wrong resolution

Tags: display

There are many posts here about people trying to set a custom resolution but they all have similar answers;

```
Uncomment and set the following two values to your preference;
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=39
```

So in my case I want 1360x768 which is value 39 above.

My problem is that I have tried all different values listed at http://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt. Also with hdmi_group=1. It never works. Everytime I reboot my Pi or Pi and TV, it always starts up in 720P which doesn't fit the screen properly. I want 1360x768.

I have also tried setting hdmi_safe=1, whilst this squashed the picture a bit, it didn't really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that the TV was actually the problem. After several reboots of both the Pi and TV (I removed all static settings regarding resolution and HDMI group etc), a change of HDMI cable, and port on the TV; It's fixed now.

So other readers be warned; Cheap TV's used as displays not for watching media, are cheap for a reason (In my case, it seems to ignore the HDMI settings being offered by the Pi at start up!).

Answer (score 3):

If your problem is cutting the edge of the screen, i think you should use the overscan options.

- overscan_left :: number of pixels to skip on left
- overscan_right :: number of pixels to skip on right
- overscan_top :: number of pixels to skip on top
- overscan_bottom :: number of pixels to skip on bottom

You can put this into the config.txt.